# Ansible - Edit a systemd service file

Tags: ansible, systemd

The systemd module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html

I'm looking for a way to add a Condition to the service file.

For instance:

```
ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/myreplication/path/
```

This would be useful for docker installations, ensuring docker doesn't start containers before a mount they need is actually available.

Sadly, it looks like Ansible doesn't support adding this right now. Am I correct there? Will I need to manually add it, or with `lineinfile`? Or is there an other way?

EDIT: This question appears to be getting views, so I'll add this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

And this answer to another question of mine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1348117/1612

To quote it:

> Don't edit files in /lib/systemd/ or /usr/share/systemd as they will get overwritten on updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This question appears to be getting views, so I'll add this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

And this answer to another question of mine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1348117/1612

To quote it:

> Don't edit files in /lib/systemd/ or /usr/share/systemd as they will get overwritten on updates.

Answer (score 17):

Let me post a solution using `ini_file` that worked for me:

```yaml
- name: Create a foo.service override directory
  file:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
    path: /etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d
    state: directory
- name: Set up foo.service override
  ini_file:
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/bar_override.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
    section: Unit
    option: ConditionPathIsMountPoint
    value: /mnt/myreplication/path/
```

This avoids rewriting the original service file, but rather adds a dedicated override into a `.d` subdirectory.

Note that `ini_file` adds whitespace around `=` as in

```ini
[Unit]
ConditionPathIsMountPoint = /mnt/myreplication/path/
```

but this is fine, see [systemd.syntax(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html):

> Each file is a plain text file divided into sections, with configuration entries in the style `key=value`. Whitespace immediately before or after the "=" is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

> *Am I correct there?*

Right, the [systemd_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) is not for manipulating service files.

Since I've had some similar questions in the past I like to share my approach.

You could either maintain your own service file template and deploy it

```yaml
- name: "Make sure the systemd service file is correct"
  template:
    src: "{{ MYSERVICE }}.service.j2"
    dest: "/etc/systemd/system/{{ MYSERVICE }}.service"
    mode: 0755
  tags: install,systemd
```

or add the necessary line via [lineinfile_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)

```yaml
- name: "Make sure the entry in '{{ MYSERVICE }}.service' exists"
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/systemd/system/{{ MYSERVICE }}.service"
    line: "ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/myreplication/path/"
    state: present
  tags: install,systemd
```

and reload and restart the service

```yaml
- name: "Make sure the service is started and enabled via systemd"
  systemd:
    name: "{{ MYSERVICE }}"
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    daemon_reload: yes
  tags: install,systemd
```

whereby it might be good to use `insertbefore` or `insertafter` also.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `lineinfile` rather than [`ini_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) to deal with files in place ?

Comment: @Zeitounator, the [ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) module can deal with structured files and sections `[section]`, which `lineinfile` isn't doing.

Comment: Well since this is exactly what a systemd service file looks like, it seems a more appropriate solution doesn't it ? And that totally wipes the need to use insertbefore of insertafter.

Comment: @Zeitounator, right, good point. I think I will do a test with that too and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zeitounator Nice, I wasn't aware of the ini_file module. And the answer itself also looks good. I'll have a look at this. It seems I can only notify 1 user at a time.

Comment: @Zeitounator Looks like "option" has to be unique. Or gets overwritten if there has to be more than 1. Whereas I believe systemd service files support a condition being used more than once: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts

Comment: So if I want to check multiple mount points, that's what I need and ini_file doesn't support it.

Comment: @U880D I am runnigng playbooks form Teamcity,what is /mnt/myreplication/path/?